# unable to update my database content

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a application,where I need to update my database content using a form and UPDATE query. Since I am new to programming got some mistake. The UPDATE query is not working. I also checked by echo $sql,still its not working. Anybody help me to solve this

```
    <?php require_once ('config.php');?>

<div class="navigation">
    <a href="proj.php" class="addbtn"><img src="back.png"  value="Back" name="submit" class="reportbtn"></img></a>
</div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $getid     =   $_GET['id'];
     $var = $row['id'];

    $sql = "UPDATE nifty SET date = '$_POST[date]', bs = '$_POST[bs]', entrypoint = '$_POST[entrypoint]', exitpoint = '$_POST[exitpoint]', pl = '$_POST[pl]', WHERE id = ".$getid;        
    echo $sql;
   $query = mysql_query($sql);
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('Updations made successfully');
</script>";
}
$sql1   = 'SELECT * FROM nifty WHERE id = "'.$getid.'"';
$query  = mysql_query($sql1);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
            $date   =       $row['date'];
        $bs =       $row['bs'];
        $entrypoint      =  $row['entrypoint'];
        $exitpoint       =  $row['exitpoint'];
        $pl =   $row['pl'];
    }
?>
<form name="testform" method="post" action="test1.php">

    Date :<input type= "text" name="date" value="<?php echo $date ?>"><br><br>
    Buy/Sell :<input type= "text" name="bs" value="<?php echo $bs ?>"><br><br>
    Entrypoint :<input type= "text" name="entrypoint" value="<?php echo $entrypoint ?>"><br><br>
    Exitpoint :<input type="date" name="exitpoint" value="<?php echo $exitpoint ?>"><br><br>
    P/L:<input type= "text" name="pl" value="<?php echo $pl ?>"><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $getid; ?>"/><br>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' class="reportbtn" value='submit'/>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have errors reporting on or it gives you some error?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). You have absolutely **NO** error handling on your query calls. You have syntax errors in your update query, blah blah blah. You need to learn basic debugging, basically. To start with: `pl = '$_POST[pl]',` <--trailing comma is a syntax error.

Comment: can you show us the update sql please?

Answer (score 1):

Learn how to get rid from sql injection.

The following update query will work.

```
$sql = "UPDATE nifty SET date = '$_POST[date]', bs = '$_POST[bs]', entrypoint = '$_POST[entrypoint]', exitpoint = '$_POST[exitpoint]', pl = '$_POST[pl]' WHERE id = '$getid'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Take care of your `$sql` variable.

You `$_POST[data]` should be `$_POST['data']`

Try like this:

```
    $sql ='UPDATE nifty SET date = "'.$_POST["date"].'", bs = "'.$_POST["bs"].'", entrypoint = "'.$_POST["entrypoint"].'", exitpoint = "'.$_POST["exitpoint"].'", pl = "'.$_POST["pl"].'", WHERE id = '.$getid;
```

and be aware that you are vulnerable to sql injection, you don't make any validation to user data input.

Answer (score 0):

You must take care of your coding style

POST method $_POST['data']

You must change your code like this :

```
$sql = "UPDATE nifty SET date = $_POST['date'], bs = $_POST['bs'], entrypoint = $_POST['entrypoint'], exitpoint = $_POST['exitpoint'], pl = $_POST['pl'] WHERE id = $getid ";
```

Example:
Update query is like this :

```
UPDATE Customers SET ContactName='Alfred Schmidt', City='Hamburg' WHERE CustomerName='Alfreds Futterkiste';
```

more find out [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)